# Recovering deleted files from full, SSD hard drive. Possible?

Tags: file, recovery, solid-state-drive

My SSD on my Macbook Pro was full. (Too much music and video). I moved a bunch of stuff back and forth between my external HD and laptop to make room to download new music. Few days later, SSD is full again AND I realise I accidentally deleted some work stuff that I really need.

Am I screwed, because my understanding is that since the hard drive is full, no recovery of what was deleted before would be possible? :S

Answer (score -1):

Since the disk is full, from a practical point of view your deleted data is gone. All blocks are used for storing  data and none is unused that could still store some old files.

From a theoretical point of view, SSDs have some spare blocks that they need for wear levelling and that are not visible to the OS. With lots of luck some of your data might still reside in one of those and could be extracted by directly reading the flash chips. But the effort for doing this would be extremely high and the probability that you will find your data is really low.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of! :(   - Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If the hard drive that contained the deleted work is full then the work has been overwritten (if it was even still there after being deleted).